# What does the Bitcoin RPC mean and how is it used?

Tags: json-rpc, terminology

What does Bitcoin RPC mean and how is it used? I see the term RPC referenced multiple times, but not show what it means and how its used. I see it in JSON-RPC. I know json is just a data format, meaning it looks something like this: { apple: red, banana: yellow }

Answer (score 12, accepted):

RPC = Remote Procedure Calls.  That describes a [system when you send a command](http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/definition/Remote-Procedure-Call) to a remote system where it's processed and results are returned.

Bitcoin RPC is synonymous with JSON-RPC in my opinion, although JSON-RPC itself is not Bitcoin-specific.  JSON-RPC simply implies that the RPC interaction will use JSON as its data structure.

Bitcoin RPC is used by authenticated clients to connect to a running instance of bitcoind. The clients issue commands to send transactions, get status, and a variety of other purposes.

The Bitcoin RPC commands are [on the wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_Calls_list).